# Padding Top and Bottom in ErrorProvider

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, padding, errorprovider

In ErrorProvider control we can use SetIconPadding(); in order to set number of pixels to add between the icon and the control.

In this way we can move icon horizontally.
How to do the same but in vertical?

I don't know how to extend or override icon positioning.

PS. SetIconAlignment() in some situation is not enough. I simply must set custom localization of icon.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately their is no *easy* way to do this.

By using the function [`SetIconPadding()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seticonpadding.aspx) you can define the space between the icon and the control only in horizontal way, but negative values are also allowed.

With calling [`SetIconAlignment()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seticonalignment.aspx) you can only put it somewhere left or right of the control, but not above or below it.

A hack to get this to work, would be to put a panel around the control you need the errorProvider for and making it higher and/or lower. Now you can set the provider on this container control instead of the meant control directly and by applying negative values for the padding you can move the blinking icon above or below the control you like.

This is some kind of hackish, but i think their is no other way to do it.

```
    +--Panel----------------------+
    |               !             |
    |     +------------------+    |
    |     | ControlWithError |    |
    |     +------------------+    |
    |                             |
    +-----------------------------+
```

As above to see, set the ErrorProvider not on the control. Set it to the panel and set `IconAlignment` to `TopLeft` and `IconPadding` to some negative value (eg -50) and your icon is blinking above your control you meant.

Comment: This is good alternative solution. Thank You. In free time i am going to find better solution.